# LongListSelector equivalent for Windows 8

Tags: windows-store-apps, longlistselector

I'm looking for the Windows 8 equivalent of the Windows Phone LongListSelector. The People app (under All Contacts) exhibits this behavior; is there an available control for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do grouping of data then you can use semantic zoom with GridView or ListView. GridView/ListView also supports incremental loading of data.

[XAML GridView grouping and SemanticZoom sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e)